# Потоки в С++ как лучше организовывать

Tags: c++, многопоточность

Такая проблема: есть игра просчитывающая графику в режиме реального времени. У просчета есть 2 стадии - подготовка к рендеру и сам рендер. Я распараллелил программу на 8 потоков. То есть каждый framerate программа создает 8 потоков для подготовки рендера, выполняет их одновременно и join-нит. Затем тоже самое с рендером.
Вот пример кода отвечающий за потоки рендера: (С подготовкой к нему абсолютно тоже самое)

```
        int i;
        threads_ = new thread[threads_num];
        if (page ==  1) {
            
            for (i = 0; i < threads_num; i++) {
                threads_[i] = thread(&Engine3D::thread_stage_render, this, rx/ threads_num *i, rx/ threads_num *(i+1), threads_num, alpha);
            }
            for (i = 0; i < threads_num; i++) {
                threads_[i].join();
            }
            return pixels;
            
        }
```

Корректно ли такое создание потоков каждый frame-rate и из завершение. И можно ли сделать как-то по-оптимизированее?
Заранее спасибо!
P.S. Я начал изучать C++ только ради этой игры и я переписал её с Python, поэтому строго не судите

UPD: Может нужен перезапуск потока с теми же параметрами без его переинициализации, но можно ли такое вообще как-то сделать с Thread?

Comment: Для чего несколько потоков? Подготовка к тендеру и рендер настолько тяжелы, чтобы все делать в 1?

Comment: @TheRyuTeam, да у меня разрешение игры 1024 на 512

Comment: *" создает 8 потоков для подготовки рендера, выполняет их одновременно и join-нит"* - Это чудовищно тяжелая операция. Потоки следует создавать только один раз при старте приложения. Поток рендера обычно имеет смысл иметь только один.

Comment: @user7860670, попробовал как вы сказали - производительность более чем в 2 раза упала

Comment: @FotonPC тогда в подтверждение приводите [mcve], телепаты же все в отпуске

Comment: или хотя бы покажите пример переделанного кода, потому что я плохо понимаю, как можно быстро переделать повторяющийся запуск одной функции в постоянно выполняющемся потоке

Comment: 1024/512 и 8 потоков, Вы чего, эт перебор. Почитайте как создаются новые потоки, как происходит взаимодействие с операционной системой и поймёте, что создавать потоки на каждый фрейм - ужасное решение.

Answer (score 1):

Давайте по-порядку пойдем по вопросам.

1. Создание каждый framerate нового потока - плохо по многим причинам, в комментариях к вашему вопросу уже на это указали.
2. Оптимизированней сделать можно, но без кода функции `Engine3D::thread_stage_render` тяжело дать прям 100 % решение. Попытаюсь дать общие рекомендации по оптимизации и сопровожу пвесдо-кодом.
3. По поводу update так сделать нельзя явно, да и не нужно смотритие пункты выше.

Теперь перейдем к оптимизации. Я не знаю ваш уровень знанией, поэтому постораюсь максимально подробнее, поэтому вы если что ниже знаете, то, пожалуйста, не думайте на свой счет, просто стараюсь максимально пояснить предложение, которое вам может помочь.

Я не знаю какой graphics Api вы используете, я знаком с OpenGL 3.3+ поэтому на основе его, сделаю предположения, думаю для DirectX 11/12 и Vulkan будут похожие вещи.

**Предполгаю** (что важно) вы в ваших потоках накладываете фильтры / подготавливаете буффер с пикселями или что-то еще. в любом случае вам нужно передать его конечный буффер графическому ускорителю. Подобные операции удобней делать на самом графическом устройстве в шейдерах в формате OpenGL 3.3 и выше вы можете писать вертексные, фрагментые, геометричесие шейдеры. Cначала делаются вертекстные, затем фрагментые, потом геометрические.

Детальнее почитайте цикл статей на [learnopengl](https://learnopengl.com/) или перевод на [хабре](https://habr.com/ru/post/310790/)

Немного вводных:

**Вертексный шейдер** - работает с вершинами, нормалями и проствляет GL_Position для вершины, используя матрицы проекции, текущую матрицу отображения( куда смотриит) от камеры и матрицу входной модели, для которой сделан translate / scale / rotation.

**Фрагметный шейдер** - проставлятет цвет для каждой вершины, там обычно делают смешивание цветов, освещение, фильты и т.д, используя данные от вертексного шейдера

Геометрический шейдер - дополнительная работа с геометрий, мне кажется в вашем случае не так интересно, но в преденных ссылках там есть информация.

Пcевдокод:

```
/// получаем на вход позицию / нормаль / текстурную координату 
const char* modelVertVertex = R"(
    #version 330 core
    layout (location = 0) in vec3 aPos;
    layout (location = 1) in vec3 aNormal;
    layout (location = 2) in vec2 aTexCoords;

    // выходные данные для фрагметного шейдера
    out vec2 TexCoords;
    out vec3 surfaceNormal;
    out vec3 toLightVector;
    out float visibility;

    uniform mat4 model; // матрица модели 
    uniform mat4 view; // матрица вида от камеры
    uniform mat4 projection; // матрица проекции
    uniform vec3 lightPosition;

    uniform bool isFakeLight;

    const float density = 0.0035;
    const float gradient = 5;

    /// проставляем gl_Position и подготавливаем данные для фрагметного шейдера
    /// в данном примере работаем с освещением по алгоритму Phong'а
    void main()
    {
        TexCoords = aTexCoords;
        vec4 worldPosition = model * vec4(aPos, 1.0);
        vec4 positionRelativeToCamera = view * worldPosition;
        gl_Position = projection * positionRelativeToCamera;

        vec3 actualNormal = aNormal;

        if(isFakeLight == true) {
            actualNormal = vec3(0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
        }

        surfaceNormal = (model * vec4(actualNormal, 0.0)).xyz;
        toLightVector = lightPosition - worldPosition.xyz;

        float distance = length(positionRelativeToCamera.xyz);
        visibility = exp(-pow((distance*density), gradient));
        visibility = clamp(visibility, 0.0, 1.0);
    }
)";

const char* modelFragVertex = R"(
    #version 330 core
    /// конечные данные 
    out vec4 FragColor;

    in vec2 TexCoords;
    in vec3 surfaceNormal;
    in vec3 toLightVector;
    in float visibility;

    uniform sampler2D textureSampler;
    uniform vec3 lightColor;
    uniform vec3 skyColour;
    /// Здесь кроме освещения и цвета, делается туман (fog)
    void main()
    {
        vec3 unitNormal = normalize(surfaceNormal);
        vec3 unitLightVector = normalize(toLightVector);
        float nDotl = dot(unitNormal, unitLightVector);
        float brightness = max(nDotl, 0.2);
        vec3 duffuse = brightness * lightColor;
        vec4 textureColour = texture(textureSampler, TexCoords);
        if(textureColour.a < 0.5) {
            discard;
        }
        /// смешиваем цвета и отдаем
        FragColor = vec4(duffuse, 1.0) * textureColour;
        FragColor = mix(vec4(skyColour, 1.0), FragColor, visibility);
    }
)";

struct VertexBuffer {};

struct IndexBuffer {};

struct VertexArray {
    VertexBuffer vertexBuffer;
    IndexBuffer indexBuffer;
};

#pragma pack(push, 1)
    struct RenderVertex {
        vec3f Position;
        vec3f Normal;
        vec2f TextureCoords;
    };
#pragma pack(pop)
    struct RenderBuffer {
        unsigned int maxVerticesCount = 100000; /// максимальное количество вершин в буффере для одной отрисовки
        unsigned int maxIndicesCount = maxVerticesCount;

        VertexArray::Ptr vertexArray;
        VertexBuffer::Ptr vertexBuffer;

        RenderVertex* quadBuffer = nullptr;
        RenderVertex* quadBufferPtr = nullptr;
    };

struct Pixel {
    float r, g, b, a;
}

//// Очень примитивная реализация, как пвесдокод показать логику работы, требует доработок. ////
struct ThreadSafePixelBuffer {
    /// ctor / dtor ///
        
    void addPixel(Pixel& pixel) {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock{m_mutex};
        m_pixels.emplace_back(pixel);
    }
    
    void setPixelBuffer(const std::vector<Pixel>& pixelBuffer) {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock{m_mutex};
        m_pixels = pixelBuffer;
    }
    
    void clear() {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock{m_mutex};
        m_pixels.clear();
    }
    
    /// именно const, так как мы иначе возможна модификация вектора без механизмов синхнонизации, 
    /// что приведет к основным проблемам многопоточки.
    const std::vector<Pixel>& getPixels() const {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock{m_mutex};
        return m_pixels;
    }
    
    std::vector<Pixel> m_pixels;
    mutable std::mutex m_mutex;
};

class OpenGLRender {
public:
    ~OpenGLRender() {
        if(m_effectsThread.joinable())
            m_effectsThread.join();
    }
    void setup(vec2u winSize);
    void render(std::vector<GameObject>& objects);
private:
    void effectsThread();
    
    void setupGL();
    void preRender(std::vector<GameObject>& objects);
private:
    VertexArray m_vertexArray;
    RenderBuffer renderBuffer;
    
    std::thread m_effectsThread;
    std::mutex m_mutex;
    
    std::atomic_bool m_running = true;
    std::condition_variable m_waitPixels;
    
    ThreadSafePixelBuffer pixelBuffer;
}

void OpenGLRender::setup(vec2u winSize) {
    m_winSize = winSize;
    /// .vert = вершинный шейдер / .frag = фрагметный
    m_shader.create(modelVertVertex, modelFragVertex);
    setupGL();
    
    
    m_effectsThread = std::thread(&OpenGLRender::effectsThread, this);
    m_effectsThread.detach();
}

///////////// Основные моменты /////////////


OpenGLRender::effectsThread() {
    /// выделяем buffer для работы ///
    std::vector<Pixel> effectPixelBuffer{m_winSize.x * m_winSize.y};
    
    while(m_running) {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(m_mutex);
        // пока pixelBuffer пустой не тратим процессорное время и поток усыпляется / блокируется и mutex снимается.
        m_waitPixels.wait(lk, [this] {
            !pixelBuffer.empty();
        });
        
        const auto& pixels = pixelBuffer.getPixels();
        /// что - то с ними делаем ///
        effectPixelBuffer[0].r = pixels[0].r * 0.1;
        effectPixelBuffer[0].g = pixels[0].g * pixels[1].g;
        ///
        
        pixelBuffer.setPixelBuffer(effectPixelBuffer);
        effectPixelBuffer.clear(); // если содержит актуальные данные только на 1 кадр
    }
    
}


void OpenGLRender::setupGL() {
    renderBuffer.vertexArray = VertexArray::Create();
    
    //// если набралось в больше maxVerts отрисовавыем первые maxVerts за 1 первую отрисовку, и потом остаток
    //// Данная система - часть BatchRender. Собираем вершины и разом отрисовываем
    
    renderBuffer.vertexBuffer = VertexBuffer::Create(renderBuffer.maxVerticesCount);

    delete[] bufferData;
    /// вершинный шейдер первые строчки
    vertexBuffer -> setAttributeLayout( {
        {ElementType::Float3, "Position"},
        {ElementType::Float3, "Normal Vector"},
        {ElementType::Float2, "Texture Coords"},
    });

 
    IndexBuffer::Ptr indexBuffer = IndexBuffer::Create(indexBuffer,
                                                 renderBuffer.maxIndicesCount * sizeof(uint32_t));

    delete[] indexBuffer;

    renderBuffer.vertexArray -> setVertexBuffer(vertexBuffer);
    renderBuffer.vertexArray -> setIndexBuffer(indexBuffer);


    renderBuffer.vertexArray -> unBind();
    
    projecton = calcProjectionMatrix(FOV, m_winSize, zNear, zFar);
    m_shader.setMatrix("model", projection.getMatrix());
}

void OpenGLRender::preRender(std::vector<GameObject>& objects) {
    m_shader.setMatrix("view", m_camera.getViewMatrix());
    
    //// Подготавливаем buffer для отрисовки ///
    
    /// смещаем на начало для рассчитвания сколько байт надо добавить
    renderBuffer.quadBufferPtr = renderBuffer.quadBuffer;
    
    /// cмещаем renderBuffer.quadBufferPtr
    for(auto& it: objects)
        renderBuffer.addRenderVertices(it.getRenderVertices());
    
    auto size = uint32_t((uint8_t *) renderBuffer.quadBufferPtr
                                    - (uint8_t *) renderBuffer.quadBuffer);
    renderBuffer.vertexBuffer -> setData(renderBuffer.quadBuffer, size);
    /// под капотом - самое важное сейчас !!!! ///
    / glBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0, size, data); / добавляем данные для отрисовки на графический ускоритель.
    glBufferSubData - тяжелая операция, поэтому и страемся сразу отдать что нам надо и сколько.
    //// под капотом - самое важное сейчас !!!!
    
    /// прокидваем данные в шейдер 
    m_shader.set("lightColor", vec3f{0.4, 0.3, 0.2});
    m_shader.set("skyColour", vec3f{0.4, 0.3, 0.2});
    m_shader.set("lightPosition", vec3f{1000, 20, -30});
    m_shader.set("isFakeLight", false);
    /// прокидваем данные в шейдер 
    
    std::vector pixels;
    /// читаем текущий Buffer
    glReadPixels(&pixels[0], m_winSize.x, m_winSize.y);
    pixelBuffer.setPixelBuffer(pixels);

}

void OpenGLRender::render(std::vector<GameObject>& objects) {
    preRender(objects);
    renderBuffer.vertexArray -> Bind();
    /// Так же тяжелая операция, поэтому страемся делать минимальное кол-во раз.
    /// для понимая на мощнлой машине отрисовка 1000 раз 1000 различных объектов уже просаживает fps до минимума.
    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES,
                      static_cast<GLsizei>(m_renderBuffer.indexCount),
                      GL_UNSIGNED_INT,
                      nullptr);
    renderBuffer.vertexArray -> unBind();
    /// для данной отрисовки - все :)
    pixelBuffer.clear();
}


///////////// Основные моменты /////////////


class Application {
public:
    /// ctor / dtor ///
    void run();
private:
    void setup();
    void handleOSEvents();
    void update(float deltaTime);
    void render();
private:
    Window m_window;
    OpenGLRender m_render;
    std::vector<GameObject> m_objects;
};

void Application::setup() {
    m_render.setup(m_window.getSize());
}

void Application::run() {
    setup();
    
    Clock clock;
    constexpr int maxFrames = 60;
    constexpr float frameTime = 1.F / static_cast<float>(maxFrames);
    float processedTime = 0.F;
    
    while(window.isOpen) {
        float elapsedTime = clock.getElapsedTime();
        processedTime += elapsedTime;
        while(processedTime >= frameTime) {
            handleOSEvents();
            update(frameTime);
        }
        render();
    }
}

void Application::handleOSEvents() {
    OSEvent event{};
    while(m_window.pollEvents(event)) {
        if(event.type == OSEvent::KeyPressed && event.key.code == OS::Keyboard::Esc)
            window.close();
        /// Keyboard / Mouse events
    }
}

void Application::update(float deltaTime) {
    /// update GameObjects using deltaTime ///
    for(auto& it:m_objects)
        it.update(deltaTime);
}

Application::render() {
    m_window.clear(Colors::Blue);
    
    m_render.render(m_objects);
    
    m_window.swapBuffers() // переставляем передний / задний buffer
}


int main() {
    Application app{vec2u{1024, 512}, "MyGame"};
    
    try {
        app.run();
    }
    catch(const std::exception& exception) {
        std::cerr << "Exception thrown:" << exception.what() << "\n";
        return -1;
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

По поводу псевдокода, обратите внимание так как передача данных на граф. ускоритель тяжелая и долгая операция, `OpenGLRender` старается за 1 раз отдать новые данные и отрисовать. Так же стоит обратить что время кадра ограниченно для 60 fps время кадра 16 миллисекунд, за это время надо все сделать, а лучше с запасом. В вашем коде, вы каждый кадр создается n потоков, делаете работу, и ждете пока они выполнится, то есть в лучшем случае выигрыш в многопотчке - если ваш алгоритм очень быстрый, но так же не стоит забывать, что вам нужно вернуть buffer на тот где поток где у вас создан графический контектс, в рамках OpenGL точно, что если вы создали графический контекст, буфферы и т.д условно на главном потоке, то вам надо и рисовать на главном потоке. А так же между потоками вы должны "защищать" pixelbuffer и вам нужно использовать примиты синхронизации, также чем больше потоков, тем больше шанс или получить проблемы многопоточки(race condition, deadlock) и т.д, если  не правильно что-то сделать и скорость выполнения может быть даже хуже одного потока.

Мое предложение создать 1 доп. поток если он реально нужен для каких-то операций, которые нельзя сделать в шейдерах по принципу как сделано в `OpenGLRender::effectsThread()` и использовать `ThreadSafePixelBuffer` для передачи данных, отдельный поток крутится и делает свою работу, только когда получил новые даннные, в моей примере когда не пустой ( **обращу сразу внимание, что код примерочный, не боевой и там много моментов, которые надо доработать**), а остальное время не ест процессорное время блокируяюсь / спя и разблокируя mutex и раз поток крутится постоянно, вы можете выбирать время когда заполнить данные для каких-то действий и вполне может быть, что к моменту отрисковки он уже готов и вы просто тратите время на передачу на граф. ускоритель.

P.S по параллельные вычисления и многопоточку советую вам книгу Энтони Уильямса.
P.S.S: ваш бы код хотя бы к такому привести

```
/// 
constexpr int threadNum = 8; // constexpr C++11
std::thread threadArr[threadNum];

/// Render.cpp
if (page ==  1) {
   for (int i = 0; i < threads_num; i++) {
       threadArr[i] = thread(&Engine3D::thread_stage_render, this, rx / threads_num * i, rx / threads_num *(i+1), threads_num, alpha);
       if(threadArr[i].joinable())
            threadArr[i].join();
    }
    return pixels;
}
```